# subtree naming convention in git

Tags: git, svn, git-subtree

We are starting with GIT as a substitute for SVN. Our product portfolio has common Core proprietary libraries that were once in one SVN repo per product.
The maintenance of CORE libraries was done by merging changes across the products, so the code was tripled. We then stepped up to "externals" in SVN and kept the Core code only in one branch and with our Jenkins have a job that builds the DLLs and commits it to the LIB repository that is externally connected in other product repositories and they use only the dlls.

That is not pleasant for debugging the dlls and code changes as it takes a while when propagating a change from the code into dlls. Plus it requires a Symbol server to have debugging available.

So we want to separate the code now in GIT per Core / Product repositories and include it as subtrees.

Is there a naming convention for the subtree in GIT?

lets say we have a dir:

```
.
Core - external/subtree
Modules
Server
Libs - external/subtree
Web
AllInOne.sln
```

Note: the code is C# solutions + some frontend JS/TS

I would say **Core_subtree** or **_subtree/Core** is one idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We started using the tilda notation - every subtree starts with the '~' character. E.g. you would get

```
~Core
~Module
~Libs
Server
Web
```

The GIT subtrees are normal part of the tree in GIT repos and they cannot be differentiated as the submodules.

Basically, you can use what you want! We chose the tilda since it is short, is not in RegEx and everybody sees it.